# EF Code First from Database with IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Using VS2017, I have few related tables in DB with constraints etc. I have created blank MVC/WebAPI project with Individual User Account option, installed EF6.2.0, imported entities from DB using 'Code First from Db Model' technique, added keys to Identity User, Role, and Login inside overridden `OnModelCreating()` and created the first migration. Migration declared all Identity tables (users, roles etc) but also tables which are already in DB which is understandable. When I try `Update-Database` I get an exception saying that table is already in DB. What is the best practice to solve this problem? I was thinking about commenting out tables in migration leaving only Identity tables.

Comment: that could be because your migration is independent with internal identity migration. that being said, when you create your first migration, it assumes the database still empty so it will create all tables. simply try to switch to a new blank database  (use new database name) or drop current database

Comment: You can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator to generate your model classes and relationship and then drop the existing DB or use different DB before running migration

Comment: I could also comment out all DbSets and whole OnModelCreating() function in my context to get migration without my domain models containing only Identity tables and then create second dummy migration with '-ignorechanges', but it doesn't feel like right way to solve this problem.

Comment: that's what i do too